# Disk partition for installing windows and ubuntu

Tags: virtual-machine

create a virtual machine 1G Ram - 40G HHD, install win 7 on a partition occupied 20G, and leave the remaining 20G in install Ubuntu.
So that when you boot the virtual machine it will run both windows and ubuntu

Comment: This is not a question for SO. SO is for programming questions.  Sorry.

Comment: you're welcome! Hope someone else will help me

Comment: Your question is not clear. Consider editing it!

Comment: I fixed it! please help me

Comment: Try asking in https://superuser.com/